# Using variables inside functions that are in a class

Tags: php, class, variables, object

Im trying to call a variable that is being created in the function , how can i access this variable?

```
<?php

class youtube
{
    public function details()
    {
           $test = "asdas";
    }
}
$class = new youtube();
$s = $class->details()->test;
echo $s;
?>
```

Comment: Head back to the PHP documentation on [classes and objects basics](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php) and specifically on [object properties](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php)

Answer (score 2):

There is a couple of ways you can do it however I would do something like this.

```
<?php

class youtube
{
    private $details = array(
        'test' => null
    );
    public function details()
    {
        return $this->details;
    }
}

$class = new youtube();
$s = $class->details()->test;
echo $s;
```

Basically I am storing a details property which contains various properties and I just return this object.

Comment: I will note that there is many acceptable ways of returning the variable. I am just highlighting one way where you can return an object of data that is otherwise concealed in the class (eg. private)

Answer (score 1):

As @Feroz has suggested, you're not returning anything from the `details()` method:

```
class youtube
{
    public function details()
    {
           $test = "asdas";
           return $test;
    }
}
$class = new youtube();
$s = $class->details();
echo $s;
```

or

```
class youtube
{
    public $test;
    public function details()
    {
           $this->test = "asdas";
           return $this;
    }
}
$class = new youtube();
$s = $class->details()->test;
echo $s;
```

Further reading on [variable scope can be found in the documentation.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Comment: There are myriad ways to do it, but as @MichaelBerkowski has suggested, a good refresh in PHP (and programming) basics might serve you well.